# Link (react-router-dom) to same location with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Consider a Link like this:
`` <Link to={`/samelocation/${id}`} state={{ state1: 'hello' }}> ``

The link resides in a sub-component of the main component (element) at `/samelocation/:id`. To test if the state gets passed correctly I added following lines:

```
const location = useLocation()
console.log(location.state?.state1 || null)
```

Indeed I see `hello` getting logged to the console.

The problem is that since it goes to the same location, it doesn't refresh the page. To fix this, I added `reloadDocument` to the link: `` <Link reloadDocument to={`/samelocation/${id}`} state={{ state1: 'hello' }}> ``.

However, now my state doesn't pass as intended and I get `null` logged to the console.

My Route in App.js just looks something like this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/samelocation/:id' element={<ConsoleLogPage />} />
</Routes>
```

Is there a way to tell `<Routes>` or `<Link>` to consider every `/samelocation/:id`-route with a different `:id` as a completely separate and new page and handle it like that?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? If the `location` variable is updated by the hook, can't the React component apply all the appropriate changes itself, without needing to reload everything?

Comment: @DBS Yes, but I feel like at that point you might as well treat it as a new page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the remounting of the component when the :id changes, you can use the key prop on the  element in your App.js. The key prop allows you to specify a unique identifier for each instance of the component, and changing it will force a remount.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path='/samelocation/:id'
        element={<ConsoleLogPage />}
        key={(route) => route.params.id}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

```
<Link to={`/samelocation/${id}`} state={{ state1: 'hello' }}>Go to Same Location</Link>
```

Comment: Yh I would think that would work and I've already tried something similar. I tried your suggestion now as well. That's exactly the kind of solution I am looking for, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Was it more of a guess or did this actually work for you?

Comment: @StackerCen I am certain this was just a spitball to see what might stick. It won't work at all though.